# How to make binary search tree in MATLAB

Tags: binary-tree

I am trying to make a binary search tree in MATLAB just like how you would do it in java or C++, and fill the nodes with characters. I understand that the nodes can be made with a struct, but I can't understand how to connect them so that it becomes a binary tree.

My struct has the following fields: `left` (for the node with the lower value), `value`, and `right` (for the node with a higher value).

Comment: Honestly, in MATLAB I'd use an array representation for binary trees. Please note that the tag [tag:matlab-guide] is for MATLAB's GUI development tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an array of your struct, and use the array index instead of a pointer. So with your struct:

```matlab
node = struct('left',[],'right',[],'value',0);
```

you can add a node like so:

```matlab
node(2).value = 1;
node(1).left = 2;   % the index of the new node
```

creating a tree where `node(2)` is the left child of `node(1)`.

`isempty(node(i).left)` means that node `i` has no left child.